# Getting every char of the line and then encrypting it

Tags: c, encryption

Why doesnt it copy every line correctly from `afile` to `bfile` inside the function `copy()`?

The problem is in `encr()` method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int copy(FILE *afile, FILE *bfile){
    char line[100];
    while(fgets(line, 100, line) != NULL){
         fprintf(bfile, "%s\n", line);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *afile;
        FILE *bfile;


        input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        copy(input, output);
        fclose(output);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need loop like as `for(index=0; (p=line[index]) != '\0'; index++){ ... }`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, it encypts in Windows, but do you know why it encrypts to a bunch of weird chars in Linux?

Comment: The results do not have the same?
I have no idea.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, yes it gives the correct output on Windows, but on Unix it's  a bunch of chars :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the line in for loop, something like:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), input) != NULL){
    for (index = 0; line[index] != 0; index++) {
        p = line[index];
        ...
        ...
        fputc(c, output);
        //index++; remove this line
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I do '\0' instead of 0? Whats the difference? @Ritesh

Comment: @Kemal P when you say 'A', it is actually 65 . When you say '\0', that actually is 0.